# Subsetsum using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, substring

I have the following code in javascript which is not running

html

```
 <p id="demo"></p>
```

---

JS

```
function isSubsetSum(arr, n, sum) {
  if (sum == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  if (n == 0 && sum != 0) {
    return false;
  }
  if (arr[n - 1] > sum) {
    return isSubsetSum(arr, n - 1, sum);
  }
  return isSubsetSum(arr, n - 1, sum) || isSubsetSum(arr, n - 1, sum - arr[n - 1]);
}
function findPartiion(arr, n) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  if (sum % 2 != 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return isSubsetSum(arr, n, sum / 2);
}
var arr = {3,1,1,2,2,1};
var n = fruits.length;
if (findPartiion(arr, n) == true) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Can be divided into two 
  subsets
    of equal sum ";
} else {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Can not be divided into two 
  subsets of equal sum ";
}
```

I am not getting any output from my javascript with html code above what i have added.
When i execute the code there is no output for this.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of error (see the console), anyway:

- `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){` is not javascript, `int` should be replaced with `var`
- Array should be defined with brackets `[]` and not grace `{}` (that defines objects)
- `var n = fruits.length` fruits isn't defined (probably should be arr)

See following working snippets, please:

```js
function isSubsetSum(arr,n,sum)
{
  if (sum == 0){
    return true;
  }
  if (n == 0 && sum != 0){
   return false;
  }
  if (arr[n-1] > sum){
    return isSubsetSum (arr, n-1, sum);
  }
  return isSubsetSum (arr, n-1, sum) || isSubsetSum (arr, n-1, sum-arr[n-1]);

}

function findPartiion (arr, n)
{
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  if (sum%2 != 0){
    return false;
  }
  return isSubsetSum (arr, n, sum/2);
}

var arr = [3,1,1,2,2,1];
var n = arr.length;

if (findPartiion(arr, n) == true){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Can be divided into two subsets of equal sum";
}
else{
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Can not be divided into two subsets of equal sum";
}
```

```html
 <p id="demo"></p>
```

I hope it helps you. Bye.

Comment: i does appreciate ,i was trying to convert a java version of the same

Comment: I suspected it, due the use of the keyword `int`, I'm glad it helped you. Bye.